# Clone git using ftp: Server denied you to change to the given directory

Tags: git, ftp

I try to clone git using ftp

```
ftp://annejulie%40blue-world.pl:password@blue-world.pl:21/home/kunass2/git/annejulie.blue-world.pl.git
```

What is wrong that server denied me to access the files?

**annejulie@blue-world.pl** has an right to follow path on my server: /home/kunass2/domains/annejulie.blue-world.pl.

I am just learning about this topics, and looking for solution to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ftp server is probably configured to give access to directories under /home/kunass2/domains, not the home directory so you can't go up then back down to the git directory.

To confirm this, don't use git, just an ftp client and see which directories you can change to.

Comment: It depends on me which directories will be accessed by user, including /home/kunass2. In this case i decided ti give an access to path like i said in a question

Comment: Can you cd to /home/kunass2/git/annejulie.blue-world.pl.git from an ftp client?

Comment: i think you're right. If i cd /home/kunass2/domains/annejulie.blue-world.pl then i get 'there is no such file and directory'. What should i do in this case?

Comment: Login to ftp and type pwd to see where you are. cd to /home/kunass2/ and use ls to see which directories you can see and see if you can find the git directory.  If not, it will be the ftp server and you'll have to change its configuration.  I can't give more exact instructions as I don't know which ftp server you are using.

Comment: when i type pwd i get '/'. Which server do i use? unixstorm.org. What do You need it for?

Comment: If i change the access for this ftp to /home/kunass2 i can see the directory with my git repos.

Comment: If /home/kunass2 is now / on the ftp server, you'll have to use /git/annejulie.blue-world.pl.git in the git url

Answer (score 0):

I have got this error when in the FTP client i have set the server's directory "/" thinking it will be considered as a FTP root directory, not system root directory. So maybe you have defined wrong path or one which the FTP user is denied to access (permissions, rights).